# How to acess a public variable inside a private variable in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have the following class in PHP:

```
class myClass extends AJAX_Callable {

public static $classGlobal = 'myVariable' ;

private static $types_fields = array(

        'myArray' => array(

            'name' => $classGlobal,

             'age' => 'twenty five')
    );
}
```

But this is not working

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible in PHP. You can't do expressions in class properties.

Comment: Won't work. And doesn't even make sense.

Answer (score 1):

From [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> Class member variables are called "properties". You may also see them referred to using other terms such as "attributes" or "fields", but for the purposes of this reference we will use "properties". They are defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private, followed by a normal variable declaration. This declaration may include an initialization, **but this initialization must be a constant value**--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

the only way I can think of doing it would be to move things into a constructor.  But its still a really weird thing to want to do. There wouldnt be any point in using `static` as you cant use it in the conventional way.

```
class myClass extends AJAX_Callable {

    public static $classGlobal;
    private static $types_fields;

    public function __construct() {
        // parent::__construct(); // if you have one

        $this->classGlobal = 'myVariable';

        $this->types_fields = array(
        'myArray' => array(
            'name' => $this->classGlobal,
             'age' => 'twenty five')
        );
    }

    public function getTypes() {
        return $this->types_fields;
    }
}



$foo = new myClass();

var_dump($foo->getTypes());
```

[fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/96wr-34e1)